# Writing a shell - how to determine the executable path and file name for the different exec calls

Tags: c++, linux, shell, posix

I have a project to write a shell in C++ on a linux OS that can run a subset of the commands a terminal can run like `cd`, `ls`, etc.

My question is, if I use something like `execl("bin/ls","ls")` how does it know where to the execute the `ls` from.  Will it default just to run the `ls` from the directory the program is being run from.  And if so how do I change where it's running from like if I run `cd foo` and then running ls again.
Yeah I'm making pretty much a limited version of bash.

Here's what I have so far for running ls.

int quash::ls(string path)

```
{
        pid_t child = 0;
        child = fork();

        if (child < 0)
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "process failed to fork\n" );
            return 1;
        }
        if (child == 0)
        {
            wait(NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            execlp("/bin/ls", "ls");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Will execlp()"/bin/ls","ls"); print anything out or will I have to add something else?

Comment: This sounds more like a "shell" than a "terminal emulator".  Presumably you would either use chdir(2) before calling your exec()-family function, or pass the desired directory as an *argument* depending on the behavior you want.

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable might play a role ...

Comment: It looks like you want to code a shell (like `bash` or `sash`), not a terminal emulator (like `xterm`). Study the source code of existing free software shell.

Comment: In answer to your edited question(s): if `execlp` runs then it will print out the current directory; if it fails it will return in the child and you have to determine why by interrogating `errno` and then print out print out an appropriate message yourself before exiting to return to the parent.  But unless you are planning on writing a separate function for every possible command (and all possible combinations of parameter therein) this is the wrong way to do it.  You only need one `execlp` and have everything call that.

Answer (score 3):

**Summary**

If you call `execl("bin/ls", "ls")` then the system will try to find a file called `ls` in a directory called `bin` inside the current working directory. That is almost certainly *not* what you want to do. You probably either want:

```
execlp("ls", "ls);
```

or

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls");
```

Although it is also possible that neither of these is really what you want.

**More details**

There are a number of different functions which can be used to replace the currently running process with new process image; these include, at least, the following:

```
execl,  execv
execle, execve
execlp, execvp
```

The versions which include an <kbd>l</kbd> are *variadic*; they take a NULL-terminated list of `const char*` arguments which define the `argv` vector which should be passed to the new executable. The versions which include an <kbd>v</kbd> instead take a single `char*const[]` argument, which is  NULL-terminated array of strings which are used to construct the `argv` vector.

The versions which end in `e` take one extra argument, which is a `char *const[]` used to construct the new executable's environment variables. The other versions use the existing collection of environment variables.

The versions which end in `p` handle the first argument differently, in two ways:

1. If the first argument does not contain a <kbd>/</kbd>, then the (current) `PATH` environment variable is used to find the correct directory. The `PATH` variable is expected to be a list of directory paths separated by <kbd>:</kbd>, and the filename (that is, the first argument of `execlp` or `execvp`) is searched for in each directory in turn. If the first argument *does* contain a <kbd>/</kbd>, then it is handled the same way as the other `exec` variants: the first argument must be the actual path to the executable, which will normally be an absolute path (i.e. one that starts with a <kbd>/</kbd>), although it is allowed to be a relative path in which case it will be taken to be relative to the current working directory.
2. Also, if a file is found but it is not recognized as an executable binary, it will be treated as a *shell* script, by being passed to the default shell (usually `/bin/sh`). The non-`p` `exec` versions just return an error in this case. (This is not the same as  "shebang" execution, which is not specified by Posix, but which will generally be performed by the system image loader so that it will work with any `exec` variant.)

For shell interpreters, the <kbd>v</kbd> versions are a lot more convenient. It's unfortunate that there is no version which offers both <kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> options (although the GNU C library `glibc` does provide one, `execvpe`) because without that possibility, there is no way to get automatic path lookup with the current `PATH` variable; only with the new `PATH` variable.

References:

1. Posix definition: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execl.html
2. Linux manpage for `execve` (in `glibc`, all the other `exec` variants end up calling `execve`): http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve
3. Linux manpage for the remaining `exec` variants: http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec